# MYSQL - Usando SUM com Join

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho 3 Tabelas

**Tabela** `Produtos` com as colunas `id`,`descricao`,`peso`. 
**Tabela** `op_itens` com as colunas `id_op`, `id_prod (chave estrangeira da tabela Produtos com a coluna id)`, `qtd`.

Quero fazer uma soma da quantidade de peso total da **Tabela op_itens**

exemplo:

**Tabela Produtos**
id.|descricao.|peso
1 |Lápis.........|0,12
2 |Borracha...|0,02

**Tabela op_itens**
id.|id_prod.|qtd
1..|1...........|5
1..|2...........|10

Queria um resultado de quantidade total do itens que neste caso é 15.
e Total de Peso que seria 0,8

Eu tentei vários comando `SELECT SUM`, mas está me retornando valores que não está correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT O.ID_OP, SUM(O.QTD) AS QUANT, SUM(O.QTD * P.PESO)
    FROM OP_ITENS O
    LEFT JOIN PRODUTOS P ON O.ID_PROD = P.ID
GROUP BY O.ID_OP;
```

Agrupei o ID_OP da tabela OP_ITENS e somei o que tinha nela de quantidade.
Juntei a tabela PRODUTOS e multipliquei a quantidade com o peso do mesmo produto.

Comment: Deu certo valeu mesmo, vc não tem noção os códigos mega complicados que achei de exemplo, e o seu bem fácil.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado. Sucesso aí !!

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que fazer o SUM com os campos peso,qtd, talvés os seus valores estejam vindo errados pelo fato do join.

Veja se assim resolve seu problema.

```
select count(total), SUM(peso) as peso, SUM(qtd) as qtd from
(
   Select 1 as total, peso , qtd from Produtos P
   join op_itens I
   on I.id_prod = P.Id
)t
```

Comment: Obrigado , esse t no final, qual função dele?

Comment: É  o nome do sub select é como se fosse uma tabela interna

Comment: Entendi, mas não deu certo, a qtd você colocou from produtos, mas ela não se encontra em produtos, mas sim em op_itens. Mas eu consegui entender o que você fez, muito obrigado pela ajuda.